# Admissible Heuristic wiki

Tags: shortest-path

I couldn't understand the following part on admissible heuristic on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_heuristic).
How does it reach that they have to be equal? Admissible heuristic only says the eval needs to be equal/less than the true cost.

> If our heuristic is admissible it follows that at this penultimate step Teval = Ttrue because any increase on the true cost by the heuristic on T would be inadmissible and the heuristic cannot be negative.

Thanks!